# How can I access my db in a PageFilter and make data available to the PageModel?

Tags: c#, razor-pages, asp.net-core-3.1

I have a working `ActionFilter` which sets a `ViewBag` for use in my MVC views:

```
public class ViewBagFilter : IActionFilter
{
    private readonly ProjectsDbContext db;

    public ViewBagFilter(ProjectsDbContext _dbContext)
    {
        db = _dbContext;
    }

    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
    }

    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        var controller = context.Controller as Controller;
        if (Guid.TryParse(controller.User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier), out Guid loggedInUserId))
        {
            // Get number of unread messages for the logged in user:
            int unread = db.MessageRecipients.Where(m => 
                m.RecipientUserId == loggedInUserId &&
                !m.IsRead).Count();
            controller.ViewBag.UnreadMessages = unread;
        }
    }
}
```

Registered in Startup.cs like this:

```
services.AddMvc(options =>
{
    options.Filters.Add(typeof(ViewBagFilter));
});
```

How would I write a `PageFilter` that could give me access to the same data in my razor pages? I am aware that `ViewBag` is not available to razor pages. Can I use ViewData? How? If not, what would I use instead?

This is what I have so far:

```
public class CustomPageFilter : IAsyncPageFilter
{
    private readonly ProjectsDbContext db;

    public CustomPageFilter(ProjectsDbContext _db)
    {
        db = _db;
    }

    public async Task OnPageHandlerSelectionAsync(PageHandlerSelectedContext context)
    {
        await Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public async Task OnPageHandlerExecutionAsync(PageHandlerExecutingContext context, PageHandlerExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        // this has to be changed:
        var controller = context.Controller as Controller;
        // this has to be changed:
        if (Guid.TryParse(controller.User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier), out Guid loggedInUserId))
        {
            // Get number of unread messages for the logged in user:
            int unread = db.MessageRecipients.Where(m =>
                m.RecipientUserId == loggedInUserId &&
                !m.IsRead).Count();
            // this has to be changed:
            controller.ViewBag.UnreadMessages = unread;
        }

        await next.Invoke();
    }
}
```

And lastly, how do I register the `PageFilter` in Startup?

I have been reading [this guide](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/filters), and they register their filter like this:

```
services.RazorPages(options =>
{
    options.Filters.Add(new CustomPageFilter(new GeoService()));
});
```

I am having several problems with that:

- `IServiceCollection` does not contain a definition for `RazorPages`. If I change it to `AddRazorPages`, I get another error:

  - `RazorPagesOptions` does not contain a definition for `Filters`.
- From what I understand, I have to pass an instance of my db-context to the PageFilter. How do I do that? This does not work: `options.Filters.Add(new CustomPageFilter(new ProjectsDbContext()));`

**Insignificant update**

I found out that I can set a `ViewData["something"]` in the code-behind files for each razor page. But I don't want to add that code to every Identity razor page, so the need for a filter remains.

Answer (score 0):

I found an alternative solution. Please tell me if it is a good one.

I made a new class, `ExtendedPageModel`, which inherits from `PageModel`, in which I am setting the ViewData in the method ´SetViewData()´:

```
public class ExtendedPageModel : PageModel
{
    protected ProjectsDbContext db;
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor;

    public ExtendedPageModel(ProjectsDbContext _db, IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor)
    {
        db = _db;
        httpContextAccessor = _httpContextAccessor;
    }

    public void SetViewData()
    { 
        var userId = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
        if (Guid.TryParse(userId, out Guid loggedInUserId))
        {
            int unread = db.MessageRecipients.Where(m =>
                m.RecipientUserId == loggedInUserId &&
                !m.IsRead).Count();
            ViewData["UnreadMessages"] = unread;
        }
    }
}
```

Then, registered `IHttpContextAccessor` in Startup:

```
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
```

And lastly, modifying each of the pagemodels. (A bit tedious.) This is /Identity/Pages/Manage/Index.cshtml.cs:

Class header:

```
public partial class IndexModel : ExtendedPageModel
```

Constructor (don't mind IWebHostEnvironment - I'm using that for somethig else):

```
public IndexModel(
    UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
    SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager,
    ProjectsDbContext context,
    IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor,
    IWebHostEnvironment env) : base(context, httpContextAccessor)
{
    _userManager = userManager;
    _signInManager = signInManager;
    db = context;
    webHostEnvironment = env;
}
```

OnGetAsync():

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync()
{
    SetViewData();

    var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
    if (user == null)
    {
        return NotFound($"Could not find user with ID '{_userManager.GetUserId(User)}'.");
    }

    await LoadAsync(user);
    return Page();
}
```